# Component without admin menu

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5

Does anyone know how to create a Joomla component that doesn't create a section in the admin menu?

I've removed all menu entries in the manifest, but it still creates an admin menu item:

```
<administration>
            <files folder="admin">
                    <filename>index.html</filename>
                    <filename>gallery.php</filename>
                    <filename>controller.php</filename>
                    <folder>views</folder>
                    <folder>models</folder>
            </files>
</administration>
```

Any ideas?

Note: this is regarding J2.5, but 1.5 is also interesting.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Joomla core code makes this happen automatically. I don't think what you want is possible. Why would you want to remove it from the admin component list anyway?

Comment: The component is only used as a component-helper for a module that needs a proxy class. Using a component is the only way I know of to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joomla will insert these menu items automatically on installation but you can get rid of them in various ways if you really want to.

The simplest way would be to change the `client_id` field for your component's rows the menu table. Admin menu items have `client_id = 1` but if you change this to some nonsense like `client_id = 10`, they will not be shown in the admin site.

Alternatively, you could delete them outright. Because the menu table uses the nested set model, you should not just delete the row. Probably your best best would be to use the delete function of the `MenusModelMenu` class.

Either of these things can be done during component installation if your installer contains a script with a `postflight` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code i ended up using for removing entries in the admin menu.

First i created an installation script that implemented the post flight method in a file called script.php:

```
<?php
//No direct access
defined('_JEXEC) or die;');

class com_mycomponentInstallerScript{
    function postflight($type, $parent){
        // $parent is the class calling this method
    // $type is the type of change (install, update or discover_install)
        $componentName = 'myComponent'; //The name you're using in the manifest
        $extIds = $this->getExtensionIds($componentName);
        if(count($extIds)) {
            foreach($extIds as $id) {
                if(!$this->removeAdminMenus($id)) {
                    echo JText::_(COM_MYCOMPONENT_POSTFLIGHT_FAILED);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Retrieves the #__extensions IDs of a component given the component name (eg "com_somecomponent")
    *
    * @param   string   $component The component's name
    * @return   array   An array of component IDs
    */
    protected function getExtensionIds($component) {
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select('extension_id');
        $query->from('#__extensions');
        $cleanComponent = filter_var($component, FILTER_SANITIZE_MAGIC_QUOTES);
        $query->where($query->qn('name') . ' = ' . $query->quote($cleanComponent));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $ids = $db->loadResultArray();
        return $ids;
    }

     /**
   * Removes the admin menu item for a given component
   *
   * This method was pilfered from JInstallerComponent::_removeAdminMenus()
   *
   * @param   int      $id The component's #__extensions id
   * @return   bool   true on success, false on failure
   */
   protected function removeAdminMenus(&$id)
   {
      // Initialise Variables
      $db = JFactory::getDbo();
      $table = JTable::getInstance('menu');
      // Get the ids of the menu items
      $query = $db->getQuery(true);
      $query->select('id');
      $query->from('#__menu');
      $query->where($query->qn('client_id') . ' = 1');
      $query->where($query->qn('component_id') . ' = ' . (int) $id);

      $db->setQuery($query);

      $ids = $db->loadColumn();

      // Check for error
      if ($error = $db->getErrorMsg())
      {
         return false;
      }
      elseif (!empty($ids))
      {
         // Iterate the items to delete each one.
         foreach ($ids as $menuid)
         {
            if (!$table->delete((int) $menuid))
            {
               return false;
            }
         }
         // Rebuild the whole tree
         $table->rebuild();
      }
      return true;
   }

}
```

Next i added an entry in the component manifest, to run the script after the component was installed:

```
<scriptfile>script.php</scriptfile>
```